# Animate a div without slowing down

Tags: jquery

I have a div which has 2 animation one after another. But once first animation finishes it slows down and run another animation. I don't want the div to slows down in between the animation, I want them run at same speed.

```
$(".div1").animate({'left':'+=200'},2000);
$(".div1").animate({'top':'+=200'},2000);
```

​

Here is I have set up on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/WQDm8/

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.
thanks

Comment: Note: The slowdown is not between the animations, it's part of the beginning and end of the animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the behavior you're looking for can be accomplished by changing the `easing` parameter described in the [documentation for `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to `linear`:

```
$(".div1").animate({'left':'+=200'},2000, 'linear');
$(".div1").animate({'top':'+=200'},2000, 'linear');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. It's because each animate is added to the queue. Do them at the same time.

```
$(".div1").animate({left:'+=200',top:'+=200'},2000);
```

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: I want them to be animated one after another not at the same time.